# Google OAuth, handle a revoked authorization

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I've been using **Google OAuth** to let users authorize access to the Calendar Service for my Web Application. After a successful [3-legged auth flow](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/3-legged-oauth-diagram.png), I was storing all user's credentials in a common file on the app Server. The next time the app needs to use the service, it will check if the credentials exist, and if yes, it will assume they are valid

code works like that

```
@Override
public void _authorize(String userId) throws IOException {

    // Check if user has already authorised the service.
    Credential credents = flow.loadCredential(userId);

    // Checking if the given user is not authorized
    if (credents == null) {

        //Create credentials now. user will be redirected to authorise 

        try {
            //Creating a LocalServer Receiver
            // Getting the redirect URI
            // Creating a new authorization URL
            // Setting the redirect URI
            // Building the authorization URL
            // Receiving authorization code
            // Exchanging it for an access token

            // Storing the credentials for later access
            credents = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, id);

        } finally {
            // Releasing resources
        }
    } else {
        // Assume the credentials are valid. so there's nothing left to do here, let's get that client
        //Update: Nooooooot! the user might have revoked the authorization, so credents != null BUT they are invalid
        //TODO: handle an Exception here, and manage the revoked credentials 
    }

    // Setting up the calendar service client
    client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credents).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

}
```

This works fine, as long as the user never changes his mind. But if the user decides to **[manually revoke](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1)** the authorization using the Google Account security options, the com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar retrieval will Fail.

**My question is** :

1. Is there a way to **check** if the **credentials** are still valid, **before trying to use them** ? 
   Else, I can only guess that the failure to get the client object, is the *only way* to have my portal realize that the credentials are no more valid ?
2. What should I do about the invalid/revoked credentials ? should I just call `flow.createAndStoreCredential` and they are going to be overwritten? Or do I have to delete the old ones first ? (how ?)

Comment: doesn't credents return null if they removed access?  Trying to find the page to remove access need to test this :)

Comment: @DaImTo no, [flow.loadCredential(id)] still returns a credentials Object that will not make it  through CalendarService initialization. And as far as I know, this is quite normal, as my Portal was not informed by any other means that the user has revoked the auth

Comment: @DaImTo I've added a link to Google Account security options. go for the 'revoke access' Button. Truth be told, it's a well hidden feature, I doubt most google users know of this option :)

Comment: @yannicuLar Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @DanielMarín Sorry, no! I've done a workaround, where, if I have a failed service call, i Will delete the stored pass, so a new auth flow will start

Comment: Ok, thanks @yannicuLar. So sad that Google doesn't provide a way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo to determine if an OAuth2 token is still valid. More information is available in the [OAuth2 guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken).

Comment: I think this solution won't work if you are using refresh tokens because the `tokeninfo` endpoint would not verify the validity of a refresh_token. I think you should handle the Unauthorized error the library will throw and respond accordingly to the client so it can reprompt the user to grant authorization

Comment: That correct, the tokeninfo endpoint only works on access tokens. If you are fetching a new access token from a refresh token, then you would need to catch the error in case the user removed authorization for your app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the refreshToken() method for this. See example:

```
// Fetch credential using the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authorizationCodeFlow;
Credential credential = authorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential(userId);
if (credential != null) {
    try {
        // refresh the credential to see if the refresh token is still valid
        credential.refreshToken();
        System.out.println("Refreshed: expires in: " + credential.getExpiresInSeconds());
    } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
        // process exception here.
        // This will catch the Exception.
        // This Exception contains the HTTP status and reason etc.
        // In case of a revoke, this will throw something like a 401 - "invalid_grant"
        return;
    }
} else {
    // No credential yet known.
    // Flow for creating a new credential here
}
```

**EDIT**
If you indeed have an invalid refresh token and you want to renew it, then you need to repeat the steps that you did in the first place to get the credentials. So:

- genererate a new authorization URL
- redirect the user to it
- user accepts the consent screen
- catch the authorization code from the redirect back to your app
- request a new token from Google using the authorization code
- create and store a new Credential using the response from Google

No need to delete the old credential. But if you want to explicitly do so, it is possible.
Something like:

```
// This userId is obviously the same as you used to create the credential
String userId = "john.doe";
authorizationCodeFlow.getDataStore().delete(userId);
```

Comment: But how do you get another RedirectUri where the user can re-authorize the app?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question:

When using the Service object for retrieving calendar items from Google Calendar, the token are automatically verified. When they are invalid, they will be refreshed automatically, and stored in the datastore you provided to the flow.

this can also be done manually. A token is valid for 3600 seconds (one hour). When retrieving a token you get this value with the timestamp when it was issued. You could manually determine if a token is valid. If it is not valid call the following async method.

```
await credents.RefreshtokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

This function gets you fresh tokens, and stores them in the datastore you provided.

Comment: I'm very sorry to say this, but I can't understand your answer, and the lack of documentation on the handling of a revoked token is not helping either. Plus, I have the understanding that refreshToken is not used to replace a **revoked** token, but an **expired** one (though the user's auth grand is still valid). You would really help me by pointing me the documentation on that use-case

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I still don't understand how the token refresh will help me. I **need to know** when the access is revoked, so I will prompt the user to repeat the authorization process from scratch.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. There has to be a way to check the authorization server and get a new RedirectUri where the user can re-authorize again.

Comment: @DanielMarín Sorry, no. I thought I've dealt with it at some point, but I haven't found a concrete solution, to test for revoked tokens. Currently, I've done a workaround, so If an authentications fails (revoke or anything else), I'm deleting the stored token, forcing a new authorization flow

Answer (score 0):

You could check token with tokeninfo and if token is not valid:
- remove credential from datastore
- invoke new auth

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    if (userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        log.info(String.format("LoggedUser: %s %s", user.getEmail(), user.getUserId()));
        Credential credential = this.getCredential();
        Tokeninfo tokenInfo = OAuth2Utils.getTokenInfo(credential, null);
        if (tokenInfo != null)
            log.info(String.format("Token expires in: %d", tokenInfo.getExpiresIn()));
        else {
            OAuth2Utils.deleteCredential(user.getUserId());
            response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI()); // recall this servlet to require new user authorization
            return;
        }
}

public static Tokeninfo getTokenInfo(Credential credential, String accessToken) {
    Oauth2 service = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), Constant.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(Constant.APP_NAME).build();
    Tokeninfo tokenInfo = null;
    try {
        tokenInfo = service.tokeninfo().setAccessToken( accessToken == null ? credential.getAccessToken() : accessToken ).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warning("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    return tokenInfo;
}
```